# Rails cant assign attributes for new entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone tell me why entity always creates with `name == nil` :

in ProductsController:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(name: params[:product][:name])
  byebug
  if @product.save
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

in view :

```
<%= form_for Product.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :categories
     attr_accessor :name
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone tell me why entity always creates with `name == nil`

Because of your `attr_accessor`. It overwrites the auto-created methods from active record (the ones that know about persistence). Just remove it.

(*assuming that your table `products` has column `name`. If it doesn't, create a migration to add it.*)

Comment: right, thanks, if rails auto-create getters and setters, what usage of `attr_accessor` then?

Comment: @nikolay: to create getters/setters which are not backed by columns in the database.

Comment: `attr_accessor` is what you use in plain ruby classes to create setters and getters for instance attributes. ActiveRecord models are actually somewhat exceptional in that they are created from an external input and not the code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ensure you're using strong params for this, otherwise the params won't pass in as expected i.e.

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  byebug
  if @product.save
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end

private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name)
end
```

More info can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: strong params has nothing to do with the issue he's having. Good idea, yes, but completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks - would they not still face the problem were the `attr_accessor` removed, without the strong params?

Comment: Nope, why would he?

Comment: Ah course, gotcha - all good for a single attribute. +1 to your correct answer @SergioTulentsev!

Comment: Strong params only kicks in when you pass a hash of attributes originating from the params. `Product.new( params[:product])` creates a mass assignment vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is not saved in database because you have used `name` as `attr_accessor`.

Create `name` column in `product` table. If you already have `name` column then remove `attr_accessor :name` from `product.rb` model.